# Automatically select series on scatter plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Using Excel 365

Here's an example that I've been working on that gets pretty close to what I want: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zZiFDaUhuZAhyHm3HZkcZrUl9KEoV97N/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108210493177158563166&rtpof=true&sd=true

Basically, I've got data A, B, and C, and for every unique A with more than one entry in the table, I want to plot B vs. C in a scatter chart with a line.  I am designing a template, and it will need to work with all permutations of data.

What I've got is pretty close to that with a few issues that I haven't been able to fix:

1. I need to allocate enough space for all possible values of A and B in the tables.  This is not a huge issue, the data sets I'm working with at the moment are pretty small, but it would be nice if it was fully dynamic, able to handle any number of values.
2. The legend shows blank entries for all of the unused columns of the table.  I only want it to show the entries I have data for.
3. The line isn't connected for non-adjacent values of B (see the line 3 for an example).  I'd like it to be connected within each series.

Hope this makes sense, feel free to ask any clarifying questions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you need to do, make every little bit dynamic (refer the animation):

[image]

---

- Firstly, instead of using blank ranges to iterate over use `Structured References` aka `Tables` --> Table named as `Table1`
- Formulas used for Columns `F3:G16` and `J2:O8` which will gradually expand.

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, Table1,
     _A, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_A),
     HSTACK(_Uniq, COUNTIF(_A,_Uniq)))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, Table1,
     _A, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _B, INDEX(_Data,,2),
     _C, TAKE(_Data,,-1),
     _UniqA, TOROW(UNIQUE(_A)),
     _UniqB, UNIQUE(_B),
     _ArrayB, VSTACK("",_UniqB),
     _DataBody, VSTACK(_UniqA&"A", MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_UniqB), COLUMNS(_UniqA), LAMBDA(r,c, 
                FILTER(_C, (INDEX(_UniqA,1,c)=_A)*(INDEX(_UniqB,r)=_B),NA())))),
     HSTACK(_ArrayB, _DataBody))
```

---

The above formula can be defined as well by using `LAMBDA()` --> So what you need to do is wrap the above formula within `LAMBDA()` --> **`parameter_or_calculation`** as `array` and replace the `Table1` as `array`. So it becomes and to be entered in **`refers to`** when defining the name as

```
=LAMBDA(array, LET(_Data, array, the rest continues as is)
```

---

[image]

---

In `Excel` sheet enter as :

```
=SCATTER_PLOT(Table1)
```

---

[image]

---

- Note that I have used `MAKEARRAY()` a `LAMBDA()` helper function instead of using `REDUCE()`, one can use `REDUCE()` as well, but it is heavy resource function and will not be efficient as `MAKEARRAY()` when stacking data.

---

- When inserting the `Scatter with smooth lines and markers` ensure to select the data range from `J2:O8` and remember to `Connect data points with line` by selecting the `Hidden and` Empty Cells` box.
- I have also used `Conditional Formatting` for the borders. here is the [Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck3w8UP6HUodtSeW5?e=Qk8dgb).

---

Comment: @DevinBaillie let me know whether using `MAKEARRAY()` worked for you or not, you seem to have deleted your comments. Found you have downloaded the file.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly.  I deleted my comments because they were based on me not paying enough attention.

Comment: @DevinBaillie but that would helped someone in the future to understand where the errors can arise.

Comment: I didn't think they added anything but more confusion.  I was reading too fast (read: not reading at all and jumped straight to playing with the worksheet you posted), and missed that SCATTER_PLOT was defined in the Name Manager, and spent longer than I'm willing to admit googling for documentation on this magic function that I somehow had overlooked that did exactly what I needed it to.

Comment: @DevinBaillie no worries at all. I understand, agree I write longer posts all the time. Do research on `GROUPBY()` & `PIVOTBY()` these are two new functions. launched in beta versions. before you miss the magic again, for future stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Possible modifications:

1. To make room for more data:

   `F3` :  `=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,ISNUMBER(B:B)))`
   `G3` :  `=COUNTIF(B:B,F3#)`
   `K3` :  `=TRANSPOSE(F3#)`
   `K4` :  `=K3# & " A"`
   `J5` :  `=UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,ISNUMBER(C:C)))`
   `K5` :  `=FILTER($D:$D,($B:$B=K$3)*($C:$C=$J5),#N/A)` copy to the necessary region.
   It's better to use here ranges really needed, for example
   `=FILTER($D$1:$D$100,($B$1:$B$100=K$3)*($C$1:$C$100=$J5),#N/A)`
2. It depends on the `Chart data range`. I don't know a method to make it dynamic (without VBA). We can define a formula which defines this data range dynamically, however if we use it here it will be calculated at once and saved as a static address.
3. To make connection between points you should change one chart option :
   `Select Data Source > Hidden and Empty Cells > Connect data points with line`

Comment: Thanks.  Just learned about the Spill operator (#), that will come in handy on a lot of projects.

Comment: With a bit more playing, I came up with this:  
`K5` : `=INDEX($D$3:$D$16,MATCH(J5#,FILTER($C$3:$C$16,$B$3:$B$16=K3,NA()),0))`  
Which will spill the whole column.  I've been messing with it trying to see whether I could spill it in 2D to generate the whole thing with one formula, but no luck so far.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok, more tweaking and I came up with this, which I think should work, but doesn't for some reason:  

=MAP(K3#,J5#,LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX($D$3:$D$16,MATCH(1,($B$3:$B$16=a)*($C$3:$C$16=b),0))))

Any thoughts on why this doesn't work?

Comment: `MAP` requires that arrays are of the same shape and size.

Comment: Your previous formula also will work only in the first column, cannot be copied.

Comment: Instead you can use for 1 column: `=VLOOKUP($J5#,FILTER($C$3:$D$16,$B$3:$B$16=K$3,NA()),2,FALSE)` and for the table: `=DROP(REDUCE(0,K$3#,LAMBDA(a,b,HSTACK(a,VLOOKUP($J5#,FILTER($C$3:$D$16,$B$3:$B$16=b,NA()),2,FALSE)))),,1)`

Comment: Yes, I see I forgot to filter the $D$3:$D$16 so it didn't work properly in the other columns.  Thanks.  I also remade what I was trying to do using `MAP` with `MAKEARRAY`  
`=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(J5#),COLUMNS(K3#),LAMBDA(a,b,INDEX(Table1[C],MATCH(1, (Table1[B]=INDEX(J5#,a))*(Table1[A]=INDEX(K3#,b)),0))))`